# ubuntu demo available

Tags: system

Is there such a thing as an ubuntu demo video or a "Take a tour" video to view prior to installing ubuntu? I am seriously considering replacing Windows 8.1 with ubuntu but I'd like to see it in action prior to making the switch.

Answer (score 3):

You can most certainly search YouTube for videos on Ubuntu, but there's something better:

Live DVD

Every Ubuntu install disk has a 'Try Ubuntu' option.  Click that to try Ubuntu without installing anything or touching your data.  It's the best way to get hands-on test drives in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you very much. After posting my question I did check YouTube and found several helpful videos.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please make sure to accept it by clicking the check box icon beneath the vote counter.

Comment: If you found a solution, please post an answer and let us know what it was.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Ubuntu online tour. It allows you to try some basic things like file browsing, web surfing, creating documents right from your browser.

See Official Ubuntu tour here: http://tour.ubuntu.com/en/

Comment: I took the tour and it was helpful. I also set up a usb drive to run the live version for a start. Next step to install ubuntu desktop AMD64 on a partition drive for dual boot purposes.